# Extract nested property from array

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

Given an array of tokens:

```js
const myArray = <const>[
  {
    tokens: ["one", "two"],
  },
  {
    tokens: ["three"],
  },
  {
    tokens: [],
  },
  {
    somethingElse: {},
  },
];
```

I want to get a tuple for the all the different literals that the tokens property has. In the above example the result should be `"one" | "two" | "three"`, however all my attempts yield `any`, unless I remove the third array item.

This is what I tried:

```js
type ArrayItem = typeof myArray extends (infer T)[] ? T : never;
type ArrayItemWithTokens = Extract<ArrayItem, { tokens: [string] }>;
type TokenArrays = ArrayItemWithTokens extends { tokens: infer T } ? T : never;
type Token = TokenArrays extends (infer T)[] ? T : never;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    tokens: ["one", "two"],
  },
  {
    tokens: ["three"],
  },
  {
    tokens: [],
  },
  {
    somethingElse: {},
  },
] as const;

type Token = Extract<(typeof myArray)[number], {tokens: unknown}>['tokens'][number];
```

Comment: Nice! That works. Thanks. Didn't know you could put types within the `[ ]` op, makes so much sense though.